# C# obtaining Powershell responses

Tags: c#, powershell

Using PowerShell I can use

```
$myMB = Get-Mailbox -Identity "test@test.com"
```

then I can get any property by using $myMB.PropertyName, i.e.

```
Write-Host $myMB.Name
Write-Host $myMB.Alias
```

In C#, using PowerShell, when I send a PowerShell command and then collect the results (just showing the section that captures results below), it just captures the Name of the Mailbox.  I'm assuming its just returning a string to the results collection, not the MB Object.

```
Collection<PSObject> results = ps.Invoke();
foreach (PSObject result in results)
{
 Debug.Writeline("Result: " + result.ToString());
}
```

How do I capture the rest of the properties?

Thanks!

Comment: `result.Properties["PropertyName"].Value`

Comment: That did the trick.  I should have known!  Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

As you've found, PowerShell wraps everything in the [`PSObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.psobject) wrapper type.

Properties (whether dynamically added through PowerShell's own type system layer, or simply part of a wrapped .NET instance) are exposed via the `Properties` dictionary:

```
foreach (PSObject result in results)
{
    Debug.Writeline("Mailbox belongs to mailbox database: " + result.Properties["Database"].ToString());
}
```